# 2sxc - Get Entity created and last updated UserID

Tags: 2sxc

DNN 9.1.1.

2sxc 9.14.

1. Is it possible to get userId or name of the user who last changed the entity and displays it in razor template?
2. Is it possible to get userId or name of the user who created the entity and displays it in razor template?
3. Is it possible to get entity history and displays it in razor template?

Also what about created and updated time of the entity?

Can someone give me some links to samples or documentation about this stuff?

Comment: For now I have find : obj.Entity.Owner to get dnn user id. Is this the right way?

Comment: and for created i use : obj.Modified

Comment: This worked for me to get the owner id: obj.Entity.Owner.Split('=')[1]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, accessing the owner is the right way - you'll have to work a bit to map it to DNN, but it's simple string splitting. Note that in some future release we'll probably change the owner mechanism to map to the guid instead of the ID, but that will still take a while and will be easy to adapt to once it happens.